# Converting char * to Uppercase in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, strtok

I'm trying to convert a `char *` to uppercase in c, but the function `toupper()` doesn't work here.

I'm trying to get the name of the the value of temp, the name being anything before the colon, in this case it's "Test", and then I want to capitalize the name fully.

```
void func(char * temp) {
 // where temp is a char * containing the string "Test:Case1"
 char * name;

 name = strtok(temp,":");

 //convert it to uppercase

 name = toupper(name); //error here
 
}
```

I'm getting the error that the function `toupper()` expects an `int`, but receives a `char *`. Thing is, I have to use `char *`s, since that is what the function is taking in, (I can't really use `char` arrays here, can I?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`toupper()` converts a single `char`.

Simply use a loop:

```
void func(char * temp) {
  char * name;
  name = strtok(temp,":");

  // Convert to upper case
  char *s = name;
  while (*s) {
    *s = toupper((unsigned char) *s);
    s++;
  }

}
```

Detail:  The standard Library function `toupper(int)` is defined for all `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Since `char` may be signed, convert to `unsigned char`.

Some OS's support a function call that does this: [`upstr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/upstr) and [`strupr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235331.aspx)

Comment: What systems normally support `upstr`? The [Debian manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/alliance/upstr.3.en.html) for `upstr` says that it is from the "Alliance CAD System."

Answer (score 10):

For those of you who want to uppercase a string **and store it** in a variable (that was what I was looking for when I read these answers).

```
#include <stdio.h>  //<-- You need this to use printf.
#include <string.h>  //<-- You need this to use string and strlen() function.
#include <ctype.h>  //<-- You need this to use toupper() function.

int main(void)
{
    string s = "I want to cast this";  //<-- Or you can ask to the user for a string.

    unsigned long int s_len = strlen(s); //<-- getting the length of 's'.  

    //Defining an array of the same length as 's' to, temporarily, store the case change.
    char s_up[s_len]; 

    // Iterate over the source string (i.e. s) and cast the case changing.
    for (int a = 0; a < s_len; a++)
    {
        // Storing the change: Use the temp array while casting to uppercase.  
        s_up[a] = toupper(s[a]); 
    }

    // Assign the new array to your first variable name if you want to use the same as at the beginning
    s = s_up;

    printf("%s \n", s_up);  //<-- If you want to see the change made.
}
```

**Note:** If you want to lowercase a string instead, change `toupper(s[a])` to `tolower(s[a])`.

Comment: Curious, why use type `unsigned long int s_len` vs. `unsigned s_len` or even better `size_t s_len`?  Seems odd to use `unsigned long s_len` and `int a` in `a < s_len`.  I'd expect the variables to be the same type.

Comment: Honestly I'm new to C and programming in general, so it is quite probable that the variable types are not the best ones.

Comment: Computing the `strlen` before iterating through a string is very wasteful.

Answer (score 6):

`toupper()` works only on a single character.  But there is `strupr()` which is what you want for a pointer to a string.

Comment: `strupr` is not standard. As far as I know it's only supported by Microsoft's library.

Comment: @interjay:  it is supported also by Greenhills and Borland.  But you are right, it is not in glibc.

Answer (score 5):

How about this little function? It assumes ASCII represented chars and modifies string in place.

```
void to_upper(char* string)
{
    const char OFFSET = 'a' - 'A';
    while (*string)
    {
        *string = (*string >= 'a' && *string <= 'z') ? *string -= OFFSET : *string;
        string++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives `bus error` when compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Answer (score 4):

[`toupper()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper) works on one element (`int` argument, value ranging the same as of `unsigned char` or EOF) at a time.

Prototype:

> `int toupper(int c);`

You need to use a loop to supply one element at a time from your *string*.

Comment: Maybe I will delete this answer, as it does not add value, but what's the reason for DV?