# How can i get first Element of Word and can convert it to Uppercase and all other to lower case?

Tags: c, arrays, char, reverse, c-strings

I have programmed a Programm that reverses me every Word in an array but my problem is i wanna have the first Letter of a Word in uppercases and all the other in lowercase.

```
C

#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

char * reversePrint( char *name )
{
    char *input_string = name;
    char temp;

    while (*input_string)
    {
        char *t = input_string;
        /* End of non Whitespace sequence */
        while (*t && *t == (unsigned char)*t && !isspace(*t))
        {
            t++;
        }
        if (t - input_string > 1)
        {
             /* Non whitespace Sequence  >1*/
            char *e = t;

            /* Reverse Words */
            do
            {
char temp = *input_string;

                *input_string++ = *--e;
                *e = temp;
            } 
        while (input_string < e);

//Paste reversed Sequence
            input_string = t;
        }
        else
        {
            //Non whitepace skip
            input_string++;
        }
    }

    return name;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "I love Pizza";

    printf("%s", reversePrint(s));

    return 0;
}
```

So my Problem is i get as a Result I Evol azziP but i have to have I evol Azzip

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Shouldn't be **I Evol Azzip**

Comment: Why does "evol" not need to have an uppercase letter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Char \* to Uppercase in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181913/converting-char-to-uppercase-in-c) and obviously there is `tolower` function

Comment: Yes but when i reverse the word and wanna change the first and the last character i got a seg fault

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following which:

- make to upper case all first char of a word.
- make to lower case all the others

I have made the code verbose so it is easier for you to understand what is going on. It can be refactored into much more compact code.

```
    void make_upper(char* line)
    {
        bool first = true;
        while(*line)
        {
            if(*line != ' ' && !first)
            {
                *line = tolower(*line);
            }
            //non first char of a word
            if(*line != ' ' && first)
            {
                *line = toupper(*line);
                first = false;
            }
            //new word ahead       
            if(*line == ' ')
                first = true;
            line++;        
        }    
    }
```

which in produces: **Nomis Tbeil !azzip**

[LIVE DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gUjtsvDOmcWXMPB6)

---

As a side note, Reverse print function is **extremely hard** to read.
Don't write long and complicated functions but instead, **write small and reusable functions** and build complex features by using those small blocks together.

Can you imagine a car manufacturer assembling all pieces of the machine in one go?
can you imagine assembling the pistons or the electronics where the chassis is assembled? Would be a huge mess.
The engine is assembled separately and only when complete is put together with the rest of the car. Do the same with software.