# Can't convert to Lower/uppercase a char* pointer using a loop in C without toupper

Tags: c, char, c-strings, string-literals, tolower

I am trying to make a function `toLowerCase(char *string)` but I am unable to make it work properly.

This is my code

```
void toLowerCase(char *string) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*(string+i) != '\0') {
        if (*(string+i) >= 'A' && *(string+i) <= 'Z') {
            *(string+i) = *(string+i) + 32;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

I am trying to loop through the string that is a `char *` pointer by accessing each element using `*(string + i)` and using ASCII to convert to Lowercase.

I am new here, if this was answered before I am sorry, but I am asking because I couldn't find a specific solution to my problem. I've tried what's in this thread: [Converting Char * to Uppercase in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181913/converting-char-to-uppercase-in-c)
but it didn't work for me either.

EDIT: This is how I call my function

```
int main() {
    toLowerCase("HELLO WORLD");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: So, I did this, as showed by PSkocik. And it worked, but I don't know why it works like this. Will the `toLowerCase()` function work with any `char *` pointer? even if I don't declare it as `char` array?

This also fixes the problem that Vlad from Moscow pointed out that I am using a string literal

```
#define T 100
int main() {
    char string[T] = "HELLO WORLD";
    toLowerCase(&string);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 3: Thank you very much for your help! I wasn't expecting to get help so quickly! I didn't know what a string literal was!

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: It seems you are passing a string literal to the function. Show how you call the function.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/X4YA5B . `*(string+i)` instead of `string[i]` is slightly unusual and I'd at least replace the magic constant `32` with `('a'-'A')`, but it does work as is.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  Is it a segmentation fault?

Comment: I just added where I call the function. I get no error, It gets stuck after the ''' *(string+i)= *(string+i)+32; ''' line and returns -1073741819

Comment: What returns that value?  When you say that it gets stuck, do you mean that the loop never ends?

Comment: The compiler returns that value. When I say it gets stuck I mean that it doesn't go further than that, because I added a '''print("something");''' after that line and the compiler didn't print it once. But if the loop never ended it would have printed it multiple times. Maybe it doesn't even detect the if condition as true, so I guess in a way, the loop never ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not change string literals. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

So instead of this call

```
toLowerCase("HELLO WORLD");
```

use at least

```
char s[] = "HELLO WORLD";

toLowerCase( s );
```

Pay attention to that it will be much better when the function will return pointer to the modified string and will not output the string. It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to output the modified string.

So define the function like

```
char * toLowerCase( char *string )
{
    // ...
    return string;
}
```

Comment: can you define a char array like that? s[] without a size?

Comment: @DavidChoi yes, that is *syntactic sugar* since you're initializing the array with a string literal.

Comment: @DavidChoi The size if determined by teh number of initializers that is by the number of characters in the string literal including its terminating zero character.

Answer (score 2):

C string literals are typed `char[]` for historical reasons, but they're effectively `char const[]`—you are not allowed to modify them.

Fortunately C makes it very easy to create a writable copy by letting you initialize a writable `char` array with a string literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void toLowerCase(char* string)
{
    int i=0;
    while(*(string+i)!= '\0'){
        if (*(string+i) >= 'A' && *(string+i)<='Z'){
            *(string+i)= *(string+i)+32;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
int main()
{
     char string[]="HELLO WORLD";
     toLowerCase(&string[0]);
     puts(string);
    //prints: hello world
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/X4YA5B

(`*(string+i)` instead of `string[i]` is slightly unusual and I'd at least replace the magic constant 32 with `('a'-'A')`, but the callee's code is otherwise OK.)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Why write `toLowerCase(&string[0]);` instead of `toLowerCase(string);`?

Comment: @chqrlie because it looks more serious

Comment: @P__J__: not as serious as `toLowerCase(&0[string]);` or `toLowerCase(0[&string]);` :)

Comment: @chqrlie agreed

Comment: @chqrlie LOL. I've simply been liking to write it like that lately. I like to see an `&` where an argument can be changed in the callee.

Comment: @PSkocik: I understand your approach, but it makes `string[0]` stand out as if `ToLowerCase` was going to modify this `char` only. When passing an array, it is more idiomatic to pass the array name or a pointer value, as in `printf("%s\n", string);`, so the `&...[0]` periphrasis is unexpected and somewhat counterproductive.

Comment: @chqrlie `puts("%s\n",string)` is different -- the array won't get modified in the call. I wouldn't do the "serious" thing there either. :) It's just a style I use.

Comment: @PSkocik: how about `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)`? or `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, ...)`? Do you use the serious version for those too?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string literal to the function `toLowerCase` and then trying to change it using `*(string+i)= *(string+i)+32;`.

You should contain `Hello World` in a variable and then pass it to the function if you want to change the `case` of characters.

Answer (score 1):

`toLowerCase("HELLO WORLD");` => `toLowerCase((char[]){"HELLO WORLD"});`
 as changing the strings literal is an UB.

your function should return the string for easy use as parameter.

```
char *toLowerCase(char* string)
{
    int i=0;
    while (string[i])
    {
        if (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            string[i] += 'a' - 'A';
        }
        i++;
    }
    return string;
}



int main() 
{
    puts(toLowerCase((char[]){"HELLO WORLD"}));
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have an infinite loop if any character in `string` is not an uppercase letter.

Comment: @chqrlie oh yes - time to go to bed

Comment: @P__J__ You should change the call to `puts(toLowerCase(0[&(char[]){"HELLO WORLD"}]));` to make it look more serious. (JK. +1)

Comment: Many a `while` loop hide a better `for` loop.