# create new converted string from "toupper()" in c

Tags: c, variable-assignment, cs50

Trying to take a lower case string, and create a new string after making characters uppercase

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    string word = "science";
    char new_word[] = {};

    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(word); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (islower(word[i]))
        {
            new_word = new_word + toupper(word[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting "error: array type 'char[0]' is not assignable".

This isn't all, and I am sure with my full program there might be an easier way, but I built out everything else, and the only point that I am struggling with is looping through my string to get a new word that is uppercase.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your variable "new_word" is being declared as a zero length char array. Unlike C# Lists and other IEnumerables, an array (even in C#) is fixed length, so you can't assign something to the zero length array. You need to give the array a length, probably `strlen(word)`. https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/c-tutorial/array-in-c And here's a "better way" to do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181913/converting-char-to-uppercase-in-c

Comment: @MM -- I retract that -- right you are, sizeof a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
char new_word[] = {};
```

Your new char array has length `0` and any access invokes undefined behaviour (UB) as you access it outside its bounds.

If your compiler supports VLAs:

```
    string word = "science";
    char new_word[strlen(word) + 1] = {0,};
```

if not:

```
    string word = "science";
    char *new_word = calloc(1, strlen(word) + 1);
```

and

```
new_word[i] = toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);
```

If you used `calloc` do not forget to `free` the allocated memory

Answer (score 1):

**Undefined behavior** when `word[i] < 0`

Avoid that by accessing the string as `unsigned char`

As per C reference about toupper()

> int toupper( int ch );

> ch - character to be converted. If the value of ch is not representable as >unsigned char and does not equal EOF, the behavior is undefined.

This is not correct, compiler gives error , *"error: assignment to expression with array type"*

```
new_word = new_word + toupper(word[i]);
```

which is not allowed with an array type as LHS of assignment.
changed to
`new_word[i] = toupper((unsigned char)word[i]);`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char word[] = "science";
    char new_word[sizeof word] = ""; 
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(word); i++)
    {
        if (islower(word[i]))
        {
            new_word[i] = toupper(word[i]);
        }
        else    /* for Upper case latter, simply fill the array */
        {
            new_word[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
    new_word[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", new_word);
}
```

OUTPUT:
SCIENCE

**EDIT:**
Just echo comment from solution given by [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74818945/20738296) and comment from 
[David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74818708/create-new-converted-string-from-toupper-in-c/74818920?noredirect=1#comment132042876_74818920)  casting is not necessary for this example. read comment below from M.M and David C. Rankin
Removed `unsigned char` from `islower()` and `toupper()`

Comment: I like your approach.  A couple of optimizations: Q: Why call the function "strlen(word)" when, in this particular case, you can use the  "sizeof word" instead? Q: Why bother with "if islower())?  Why not just assign "toupper()" for every byte?  Q: Did you notice the bug for any letter that's ALREADY upper case?

Comment: You forget about the case of filling in `new_word` with the characters that were not lower-case

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for suggestion. I will edit accordingly

Comment: @M.M thanks for your comment. I have added handling if uppercase latter present in strnig

Comment: Good job with the cast to `unsigned char`, but with `char word[] = "science";`, you are guaranteed that all characters are representable as `unsigned char`. You are correct, but good to understand why.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin a reasonable assumption to make in questions like this is that the code is supposed to work for other inputs besides just the sample input shown

Comment: Yes, that is a good assumption, but so long as you are reading ASCII, or reading with a function that reads bytes into a character array, then the same would hold. Max of any 8-bit value is `255`. Where the type passed to any of the `ctype.h` functions is other than `char`, `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, then the cast to `unsigned char` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is but one way of accomplishing the task. Make sure to come up with your way of doing.

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define MAX_BUFF 128   
    
    char *upperCase(char *c) {
        //printf("%s, %d", c, strlen(c));
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(c) && i<MAX_BUFF; i++) {
           c[i] = c[i] - ' ';  // convert char to uppercase
           //printf(">> %c", c[i]);
        }
        return c;
     }  
    int main (void)
    {
        char word[MAX_BUFF] = "science";
        char new_word[MAX_BUFF];
        
         printf("in>> %s \n", word);
         strcpy(new_word, upperCase(&word[0]));
         printf("out>> %s\n", new_word);
    }

Output:
in>> science 
out>> SCIENCE
```

Answer (score 0):

Named arrays cannot be resized in C, you have to set the size correctly to start:

```
size_t len = strlen(word);
char new_word[len + 1];   // leaving room for null-terminator
```

Note that no initializer can be used for `new_word` when its size was determined by a function call  (a lame rule but it is what it is); and you can take out the `len` loop variable since it is now defined earlier.

Then set each character in place:

```
new_word[i] = toupper(word[i]);
```

but be careful with the surrounding `if` statement: if that were false, then you need to set `new_word[i] = word[i]` instead.

(Pro tip, you can get rid of the `if` entirely, because `toupper` is defined to have no effect if the character was not lower case).

Lastly, there should be a null terminator at the end:

```
new_word[len] = 0;
```

---

NB. To be technically correct, the call to `toupper` should be: `toupper((unsigned char)word[i])` -- check the documentation of `toupper` to understand more about this.